# Spotfire Running Balance (Cumulative Sum)

Tags: sum, spotfire, cumulative-sum

I am trying to create a running balance column in Spotfire that's supposed to look like the picture attached below. In essence,I want to calculate the cumulative total of the "amount" column row by row, and that I want it to start from 0 as the date changes.

I have tried several OVER functions: 
`Sum([AMOUNT]) OVER AllPrevious([Date])`
`Sum([AMOUNT]) OVER Intersect([CURRENCY],AllPrevious([SETTLEDATE]))`
`Sum([AMOUNT]) OVER Intersect([Calculation Date],AllPrevious([SETTLEDATE]))`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Here is the Picture]

Answer (score 4):

You were very close with your first over statement. The problem is, when you use `over (AllPrevious([Date]))` and you don't have 1 row for each date, then you will skip rows. So, the last row of your data would only sum it over the rows where `6/1/2017` is in the `Date` column. Instead, we need to apply a RowID to your data set and then sum over it. This will ensure we sum over all previous rows.

Assuming your data set is in the order you want it to be in when you bring it into SpotFire, do the following:

- Insert a calculated column `RowID()` and name it `RowID`
- Use this calculation: `Sum([amount]) over (Intersect([Date],AllPrevious([RowID])))`

This will give you the running sum you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out my mistakes. Your solution worked great!

Comment: No problem @LeoL

Answer (score 1):

@scsimon- I modified your custom expression slightly to include `date` as requested in the question.

**Modified expression:**

```
Sum([Amt]) over (intersect(Allprevious([rowID]),[Date]))
```

**Final output table:**

[image]

@LeoL - Hope this answers your question.

Comment: @LeoL- Glad to help. If this solved your question, please feel free to accept the answer.